# How to develop video chat application in angular and java spring boot using webRTC?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, webrtc, videochat

I want to build web based video chat application. I am developing the application in `Angular 7` and `Java Spring Boot`. Also I want to use `webRTC` for videochat. Please share suggestions, how to build video chat using `webRTC`, `Angular` and `Java Spring Boot`.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources such as tutorials or repositories is considered [off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Additionally, even if you just asked for suggestions, the question would be too broad. I recommend that you try out some things with WebRTC + Angular + Spring, and if you're stuck with something, (like, why is the video not showing), you can post a specific question about that (and show the relevant code).

Comment: Hi, I searched on google quite a lot but didn't find anything about webRTC in spring boot. Please help suggest me how to do. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build something of this complexity on specific frameworks, you will usually have to build it yourself as there's small chances of finding the exact solution on the exact frameworks already built and released to public domain.

Where to start from? WebRTC streaming is probably the core feature you need to understand and implement for such project. You could review and deploy some samples to understand the technology, requirements, what you can achieve. 
In example, for a scalable production project you could check streaming WebRTC trough a Wowza SE relay as with this [sample html5 videochat](https://github.com/videowhisper/HTML5-Videochat-PHP) .
Then start building your own project from scratch, using the same requirements.